# Android Service not working properly?

Tags: java, android, android-service

i am trying to create a services.
i creats a service and destory my activity.but when i start activity the service becomes 2.
because one the first service and the second starts 2nd time. see my code andhelp me what am i missing?

Main acitvity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class));
   }  
}
```

i am not stoping here service because i want to send information on server after each 10 seconds , when user run my app, app starts to send data on server.
if my user finish() activity, the services keep working, but if user click on logout/exit button the service will stop the work.

Myservice.java

```
 public class MyService extends Service {
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // Let it continue running until it is stopped.

     final Handler h1 = new Handler();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                while (true) {

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                        h1.post(new Runnable() {

                            public void run() {
                            System.out.println("lay g jnab");

                            }
                            });
                        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

                }
            } }).start();

      return START_STICKY;
   }
   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
      Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
}
```

help me please?

Comment: Could you explain your question a little clearer?

Comment: @fonZ i want to send gps location on server, when a user login my app, service will start the working, if user finish or stop the activity the server should not stop.But if user again start activity and he click on logout, then service stops the working.
actually this i want

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing foreground service. [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)

Foreground service displays notification and never be stopped by an activity close. And can be stopped when needed.

Implement this code snippet in your service

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: can you explain the cycle for activity to start and stop the activity.

Comment: See here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle. This explains the Activity lifecycle.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use BroadcastReceiver instead Service

Br.Java

```
public class Br extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        // your functionality
    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
Intent multiAlarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Br.class);
PendingIntent multiAlarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, MULTI_ALARM_RC, multiAlarmIntent, NO_FLAGS);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 1000,1000*60*60*10, multiAlarmPendingIntent);
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity
     android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:screenOrientation="portrait">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver
  android:name="com.example.Br"
  android:process=":remote"/>
```

Comment: can you explain?
how i can implements broadcast recivers.

Comment: Kindly explain your answer by providing some details around BroadcastReceiver.